# OxyPlot как сделать значения по оси X текстовыми

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Мне нужно сделать подобный график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю какую мне ось использовать что бы текст выводить, и как потом загнать колекцию моих значений где одно поле строка а другое число.

Можете потбросить модельку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ось `CategoryAxis`

```
<oxy:CategoryAxis Position="Bottom" Labels="{Binding Labels}" Angle="-90" />
```

- `Position` - указывает на расположение оси, (`Bottom`, `Top`, `Left`, `Right`)
- `Labels` - отвечает за отображаемые надписи.
- `Angle` - угол поворота.

Тип линии - `LineSeries`:

```
<oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" 
                MarkerType="Diamond" 
                MarkerSize="4"
                MarkerFill="Blue"
                Color="Blue"/>
```

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По оси `X` - целочисленное значение соответствующее важности строки. Если известно что набор уже отсортирован подходящим образом то первое значение можно принять за 1 и дальше постепенно добавлять.